# Install KDE DE without any effect on unity

Tags: unity, kubuntu, software-installation, kde, desktop-environments

Yesterday I installed KDE in ubuntu 14.04 and I was quite pleased. Then I realised that the KDE install had

- messed up with fonts and all I had were ugly looking fonts (in Chrome and Firefox to be specific)
- installed all sorts of KDE apps I didn't intend to install (though I liked Dolphin)
- changed my splash screen to that of Kubuntu
- changed unity's sub-menu colour when I set up a new theme in KDE

I tried to fix these issues but when no method worked, I ended with formatting and doing a new ubuntu install.

Is there a way to install KDE without these issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a way? No, not really. We can, however, lessen the pain.  Screenshots would also help with problems 1 and 4. If you're planning on using KDE regularly it is probably worth letting it do what it wants.

1. This can usually be fixed by removing any `.gtkrc` or `.gtkrc-2.0` files in your home folder and logging out and logging back in.
2. Don't install the recommends and suggests. Run:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install kubuntu-desktop
   ```

   See all that stuff it wants to install? On my Trusty install it said:

   ```
   0 upgraded, 408 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
   Need to get 190 MB of archives.
   After this operation, 662 MB of additional disk space will be used.
   ```

   Ouch! That's a lot! Instead use:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends --no-install-suggests kubuntu-desktop
   ```

   That lowers things down to:

   ```
   0 upgraded, 204 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
   Need to get 110 MB of archives.
   After this operation, 358 MB of additional disk space will be used.
   ```

   Much more reasonable.  Granted, those recommended and suggested packages are there for a reason, you might find a few quirks, but everything in general should work in general.
3. That would be the `plymouth-theme-kubuntu-logo` and `plymouth-theme-kubuntu-text` packages.

   Either remove them, (with `apt`, etc) or run:

   ```
   sudo update-alternatives --config default.plymouth
   ```

   and pick the one you want to use.
4. Again, screenshots would help. Probably depends some on the theme too. Making sure your Unity theme is set to Ambiance and doing step 1. should help some.

Comment: as i said. I have already formatted my system. So, screenshots are not possible now

Comment: @about99ninjas Ah yes, sorry. I'm interested if this method fixes everything you experienced though.

Comment: does second method in your step 2 install KDE bloatware of any sorts?

Comment: @about99ninjas Depends what you consider bloatware, but no it shouldn't.

Answer (score -2):

changed unity's sub-menu colour when I set up a new theme in KDE
--> Solution: remove in the $HOME directory the .kde, .gconf and .config directories, logout and login again.

All ubuntu configuration will be restored to the default when reating a new user.

Comment: This is not an answer.